# saving data from an array without submitting any form php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop, save

I'm tryng to save an array so I have the following code:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM scenarii where code_s='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['code_s'])."'";
$qry = mysql_query($sql) or die(__LINE__.mysql_error().$sql);


$i = -1; // index des enregistrements
?>
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
   <tr>
      <td><strong>CODE SCENARIO</strong></td>
      <td><strong>LIBELLE</strong></td>
      <td><strong>ACTION</strong></td>
      <td><strong>DESCRIPTION</strong></td>
      <td><strong>DATE</strong></td>
   </tr>
   <form action="<?php echo (isset($_POST['go'])) ? 'go.php' : '#'; ?>" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="liasse" value="<?php echo $_POST['liasse']; ?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="n_doss" value="<?php echo $_POST['n_doss']; ?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="qualite" value="<?php echo $_POST['qualite']; ?>"/>
      <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)): ?>
      <tr>
         <td><input name="data[<?php echo ++$i; ?>][code_s]" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['code_s'];?>" size="10"></td>
         <td><input name="data[<?php echo $i; ?>][titre]" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['titre']; ?>" size="45"></td>
         <td><input name="data[<?php echo $i; ?>][action]" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['action']; ?>" size="15"></td>
         <td><input name="data[<?php echo $i; ?>][libelle]" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['libelle']; ?>" size="55"></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="data[<?php echo $i; ?>][date]" value="<?php echo $get_date($row['jour']) ; ?>" size="12"></td>
      </tr>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
```

And in order to save this I have this code:

```
if (isset($_POST['liasse']))  {
$value = $_POST['data'] ; 

foreach($value as $key => $array)
{

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO agenda SET
        liasse = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['liasse']).'",
        code_s = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($array['code_s']).'",
        date_action = "'.date('Y-m-d',strtotime($array['date'])).'", 
        libelle = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($array['titre']).'",
        action = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($array['action']).'",
        description = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($array['libelle']).'",
        n_doss = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['n_doss']).'",
        qualite = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['qualite']).'"
        ';
mysql_query($sql) or die(__LINE__.mysql_error().$sql);

}
```

But I'm really lost,

In fact I use a form for that, now I would like to submit all of this data but without any form, directly when I have the first while I would like to save it.

The thing is that I'm lost because I can not call any var like that  data[][code_s].

So I do not know how to save this. I would like to save it in background, and not to display that something has been saved.

Receive all my Utmost Respect

kind regards,

SP.

Comment: 1.) don't use the mysql extension, it is depreciated and very unsafe. Use the mysqli extension or even better: PDO.

Comment: It is not possible to make any sense out of what you ask. You will have to edit your question (grammar!) and give more details what you really want to do.

Comment: Dear Sir, I'm verry sorry, I'm a citizen from an overseas's country, So I learn english since 6 month and that is why it is not perfect. Receive my most sincere apologises for that.

What I was asking is that I have an array that receive some informations from database. I would like to save it without submiting anny form. But Directly into the database

Comment: Might it be that you want to save that array (where?) whilst _also_ handing the values out to a browser?

Comment: No problem, but I am convinced that you can correct this sentence you gave to make more sense: In fact I use a form for that, now I would like to submit all of this data but without any form, directly when I have the first while I would like to save it.

Comment: If I get that right you have an array of values you got from a database. now you want to save those values back into the database (I guess into another table?) inside the same script/same run. Without any client interaction? Then stop using $_POST, just use the array values instead when filling your sql statement.

Comment: yeah that is exactly what I would like to do. But actualy I use a form in order to do this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. A form only makes sense when asking a client to fill out a form and send it back. You claim you don't want any client interaction. So why do you use a form? Don't!No html at all required for this.

Comment: but the thing is that I only know how to insert data that comes from an html form using the method post like that Insert into `table` Set `column1` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['column1'])."'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the code od the lower code block into a function and hand over the value array as argument:

```
function storeValues ($data) {
    foreach($data as $key => $val) 
    {
        $catalog=sprintf("%s='%s'",$key,$val);
        $sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO agenda SET %s', implode(',',$catalog));
        mysql_query($sql) or die(__LINE__.mysql_error().$sql);
    } // foreach 
} // function storeValues
```

You call this function when you want to save the values. So after retrieving them from the database. You call it for each row you retrieve and hand over the values like that:

```
storeValues ($row);
```

This will store one row of values at a time. Obviously this can be optimized to use a multiple insert. But let's take one step after another...